# res.end() is never sent after streaming a file to client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, http, response

I'm basically trying to stream a file from a MongoDb to a client. The file is  received with no problem, but when the stream ends and i try to send a  request.end() the client never get it.

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    var db = new mongo.Db('prueba', new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017));
    db.open(function (err) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);

        var gfs = Grid(db, mongo);
        console.log(req.filename);
        var uploadedSize = 0,
            uploadProgress = 0;
        idPdf = new ObjectId();  //cliente crea un id de mongo, el cual se utilizara para traer el recurso despues
        console.log(idPdf);

        var grabarm = req.pipe(gfs.createWriteStream({
            filename: 'test',
            _id: idPdf
        }));

        grabarm.on("close", function () {

            var tbuffer = gfs.createReadStream({filename: 'test'});

            tbuffer.on('open', function () {
                // This just pipes the read stream to the response object (which goes to the client)
                res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=pdfmongo.pdf');
                res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');

                tbuffer.pipe(res);
            });

            tbuffer.on('data', function (chunk) {
                console.log("receiving data");
            });
            tbuffer.on("close", function () {

                console.log("fin"); //can see it in console
                res.end("ok file received");//client never sees this

            });

            tbuffer.on('error', function (err) {
                res.end(err);
            });
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: did you try `res.send()` instead?

Comment: i just tried it, it gives me an error "can't set headers after they are sent"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your readable stream finishes reading, by default, it emits and end() event, which will call the end() event on the writable stream (the res stream). You don't need to worry about calling end() in this case.

So your res will no longer be writable after the end() event is called. So, if you want to keep it writable, just pass the end: false option to pipe(). For an example:

```
fs.createReadStream("./image.png").pipe(res, { end: false });
```

, and then call the end() event sometime later.

Btw you should listen to 'end' event instead of 'close' event for stream finish cuz 'close' does not explicitly means all data has been transferred.

Comment: i set it up like like you say     tbuffer.pipe(res,{ end: false }); and changed the end event, and it still shows the console "fin" message but still its in the browser i cant get any message

Comment: According to the node.js documentation:
"By default stream.end() is called on the destination when the source stream emits 'end', so that destination is no longer writable. Pass { end: false } as options to keep the destination stream open.

This keeps writer open so that "Goodbye" can be written at the end."

    `reader.pipe(writer, { end: false });
       reader.on('end', () => {
       writer.end('Goodbye\n');
    });`
doc link: [link](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options)