# File download in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, download

I am trying to implement a download router for a nodejs app. After several downloads my app crashes. Any advice?

```
app.route( "/download" )
.get( (req, res) => {
    var filename = req.query.filename;
    var file = __dirname + '/upload/' + filename;
    var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + req.query.filename);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

    var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    filestream.pipe(decrypt).pipe(res);

})
```

I get this error:

```
    Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:243:12)
at Decipher.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:291:5)
at ReadStream.ondata (_stream_readable.js:666:20)
at ReadStream.emit (events.js:182:13)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
at fs.read (internal/fs/streams.js:196:12)
at FSReqCallback.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:473:5)
    Emitted 'error' event at:
at Decipher.onerror (_stream_readable.js:690:12)
at Decipher.emit (events.js:182:13)
at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:245:10)
at Decipher.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:291:5)
[... lines matching original stack trace ...]
at FSReqCallback.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:473:5)
```

**UPDATE**
Someone asked about decrypt, the files are encrypted using crypto module:

```
var decrypt = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password);
```

Also, after reading [res.end() is never sent after streaming a file to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651834/res-end-is-never-sent-after-streaming-a-file-to-client+?fbclid=IwAR2GMbhl6-MkqQ7E-Z2n7QXxyZ3eEitZ-GThPxtOF1Rga5WvOM5-jURKPSI) i tried this:

```
var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    filestream.pipe(decrypt).pipe(res, {end: false});
    filestream.on("close", function() {
        res.status(200);
        res.end();
    });
    filestream.on("error", function() {
        res.status(400);
        res.end();
    });
```

It doesn't work :(, i get the same error

Comment: What is `decrypt`?

Comment: my off the top of my head guess is that since you are never closing out a request using `res` your requests are hanging out in system memory.

Comment: @omerowitz i updated my question.

Comment: @DLowther yes and i tried several methods to end my request properly but nothing works

Answer (score 1):

Just use `res.download(<filepath>)`.

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download

Comment: Ok. But my file is encrypted and i have to decrypt it first. How can i decrypt it before download?

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs when we are out of memory. 
So we have to close every stream after using it.

Streams are EventEmitters so you can listen to certain events.

```
app.route( "/download" ).get( (req, res) => {
var filename = req.query.filename;
var file = __dirname + '/upload/' + filename;
var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);

res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + req.query.filename);
res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
filestream.pipe(decrypt).pipe(res);
filestream.on("finish", function(){
  res.send();
})

})
```

Comment: But if i do that, from my knowledge, i could close it too early. Right?

Comment: @AlexTurdean Not sure what you mean by 'too early'? You decide when it happens by where you place the statement in your code

Comment: @Bhuvi Anyway, i tried that for you and i get errors with memory leak detected.